# Determine the curve points

Tags: calculus

a) Determine the curve points $ x ^ 6 + y ^ 6 = 1 $ furthest and closest to the origin

b)Determine the minimum distance between the surface $ 4x ^ 2 + y ^ 2-z = 0 $ and the point $ (0,0,8) $

I had thought of constraining, taking $ z = $ distance from point of origin, and applying Langrange multipliers.

Comment: For part a, you are looking at minimizing and maximizing the square distance function between a point in the curve and the origin. The same goes for part b, except you want to minimize the square distance between the given curve and point.

Note: minimizing square distance is the same as minimizing distance, though taking the derivative of a radical function is not as easy. We make it easier for ourselves but considering the square, thus simplifying the derivative.

Comment: For (a) use that in the point of minimal or maximal distance the slope of the line joining the origin ant that point is orthogonal to the curve, that is $y'=-x/y$. Now plug that in $6x^5+6y^5y'=0$ and solve happily for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following finds extreme values by using no conditional constraint. This appeared simpler for me. (But not simpler to type... I am too slow in typing, had a break for that real life job, finally found the time to complete and submit.)

---

Let $P(x,y)$ be a point satisfying $x^6+y^6=1$. Then the points $(\pm x,\pm y)$ and $(\pm y,\pm x)$ are also on the curve and their distance to $O(0,0)$ is the same one as for the point $P$ (which is one of them), so this distance is minimal / maximal when this is the case for $P$.

Because of this we may and do assume $x,y\ge 0$.

(We could even assume $0\le y\le x\le 1$.)

Then we have $0\le x,y\le 1$. Let $X=x^6$, $Y=y^6=1-X$, we can extract $x,y$ from $X,Y$, and so we have to minimize and maximize the function $f$ given by
$$ f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\ ,\qquad X\to f(X)=X^{1/3}+(1-X)^{1/3}\ .
$$
Its derivative on $(0,1)$ is $X\to f'(X)=\frac 13X^{-2/3}-\frac 13(1-X)^{-2/3}$, and it is easy to check its sign. We have $f'>0$ on $(0,1/2)$, and $f'<0$ on $(1/2,1)$. So $f$ is an increasing function on $[0,1/2]$, it increases from $f(0)=1$ to $f(1/2)=2\cdot 2^{1/3}=2^{4/3}$, then it decreases on $(1/2,1)$ back to $f(1)=1$.

The distance ranges thus from $1$, reached on the axes, minimal value, to $2\cdot 2^{1/3}$, reached on the first and second bisectors, maximal value.

A picture for this is:

[[image: The graph of <span class=]$x^6+y^6=1$ placed between touching circiles around the origin">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WRl9.png)

---

(2) For the second point, note that we want to minimize the distance from the point $(0,0,8)$ to a point of the shape $(x,y,4x^2+y^2)$. So we want to minimize the expression
$$
g(x,y)=(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2 +(4x^2+y^2-8)^2\ .
$$
This is already an expression in $X=x^2$ and $Y=y^2$, so we want to minimize
$$
h(X,Y)\to X+Y+(4X+Y-8)^2
$$
on the first quadrant. The minimal value is taken either on the boundary, so for $X=0$ or $Y=0$, or else at a point where both partial derivatives vanish. On the boundary $X=0$ the function is $Y+(Y-8)^2=Y^2-15Y+64$, the minimal value is taken in $15/2$ and equals $31/4=7.75$. On the boundary $Y=0$ the function is $X+(4X-8)^2=16X^2-63Y+64$, the minimal value is taken in $63/32$ and equals $127/64=1.984375$. Else, the partial differentials are $1+8(4X+Y-8)$, $1+2(4X+Y-8)$, and they do not vanish simultaneously. (Because then $4X+Y-8=0$, giving rise to a contradiction.)

So we accept the point $(X,Y)=(63/32,0)$ as realizing $\min h=\min g =127/64$,  corresponding to the points realizing the minimal distance to the given paraboloid which are $(x,y)=(\pm{63/32},0)$. (The minimal distance is the square root of the above $127/64$.)

Answer (score 1):

For (b): The vector joining the point(s) of extremal distance and $(0,0,8)$ are orthogonal to the tangent plane in that point, hence we have 
$$\bigl\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\8x \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\4x^2+y^2-8\end{pmatrix}\bigr\rangle=0\text{ and }
\bigl\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2y \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\
4x^2+y^2-8\end{pmatrix}\bigr\rangle=0.$$
If I'm not mistaken there are five solutions $(x,y)$, namely $(0,0)$, $(0,\pm\sqrt{15/2})$ and $(\sqrt{63/32},0)$.